# Connectivity regresa null con provider

Tags: flutter, dart, conexión

Estoy creando una app que trabaja con Connectivity y Providerla cual tiene que estar al tanto de la conexión a internet y funciona cunado tiene conexión pero cuando no hay conexión y hago un restart avisa que la conexion es null y ocupo que diga que esta offline y no null.

Esto es cuando inicio la aplicacion con conexion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es cuando inicio la apllicacion sin conexion a internet

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seccion donde llamo todos los providers que uso en el main:

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => DatosFederacion()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => DatosGrupos()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => DatosAlumnos()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => DatosClases()),
        StreamProvider<ConnectivityStatus>(create: (context) => 
         ConnectivityService().connectionStatusController.stream)
      ],
```

Widget donde llamo el provider de Connectivity y donde me dice que la connexion es null envez de offline:

```
class PlantelesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlantelesPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SimplePage(
      child: body(context),
    );
  }
Widget body(BuildContext context) {
    final providerDatosGrupos = Provider.of<DatosGrupos>(context);
    var connectionStatus = Provider.of<ConnectivityStatus>(context);
    log('connection${connectionStatus.toString()}');
  }
}
```

La clase que uso para Connectivity:

```
class ConnectivityService {
  StreamController<ConnectivityStatus> connectionStatusController = StreamController<ConnectivityStatus>();
  ConnectivityService() {
    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      connectionStatusController.add(_getStatusFromResult(result));
    });
  }
  ConnectivityStatus _getStatusFromResult(ConnectivityResult result) {
    switch (result) {
      case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
        return ConnectivityStatus.Cellular;
      case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
        return ConnectivityStatus.WiFi;
      case ConnectivityResult.none:
        return ConnectivityStatus.Offline;
      default:
        return ConnectivityStatus.Offline;
    }
  }
}

enum ConnectivityStatus {
  WiFi,
  Cellular,
  Offline
}
```

Answer (score -1):

El valor inicial siempre es nulo, a menos que le especifiques que valor inicial debe tener, la mayoría de los widgets tiene esa propiedad, el `StreamProvider` también.

https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html

En el `initialData` debes decirle que valor retornará al inicio, antes de hacer la llamada.